# Propositional logic - Tautological Implication question.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am wondering if someone can confirm a conclusion I have come to.
Say X is a set of formula and Z and Y are formulas. If X tautologically implies the negation of Y, and Z tautologically implies Y, X cannot tautologically imply the negation of Z, correct? As this would be a contradiction (as Z is already true, so the negation cannot be true?).. found a logic textbook in a storage locker that has my curiosity.. thanks in advance!

Comment: What logic system of logic are you using?

Comment: Formal or informal symbolic logic, just looking to confirm my suspicions

Comment: I should have been clearer.  Does the system you are using have the law of the excluded middle as the answer can be different.

Comment: Not correct; on the above hypotheses, $X \cup \{ Z \} \vDash \bot$ (inconsistency), that amounts to $X \vDash \lnot Z$

Comment: Thank you.. appreciate your time, have to read more about this

Comment: We have that $(X\rightarrow\lnot Y)$ and $(Z\rightarrow Y)$ are tautologies.

Now, the latter is tautologically equivalent to $(\lnot Y\rightarrow\lnot Z).$

Therefore, $(X\rightarrow\lnot Z)$ is a tautology, i.e., $X$ tautologically implies the negation of $Z.$

Comment: That is crystal clear.. thank you!